# CartoDB, add search box after cartodb.createLayer

Tags: carto-js

I used to use a hack I found online to add a search box to a cartoDB map, which I created using cartodb.createLayer and it used to work, but now it stopped working, the search box does not appear (no error message). Is there another way to do it?

```
.on('done', function(layer) {
      //hack from https://gist.github.com/javisantana/4e50d53e4eeb7fbdab0e
      var v = cdb.vis.Overlay.create('search', map.viz, {})
      $('#map').append(v.render().el);
    })
```

Full code is here: https://github.com/childcaremap/NYCdaycare/blob/gh-pages/dev/scoremap.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found a related question on stackexchange ([How do you add a search box to the map when creating a CartoDB visualization at runtime?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111087/how-do-you-add-a-search-box-to-the-map-when-creating-a-cartodb-visualization-at/)) and the answer was that I have to add a line now:

`var v = cdb.vis.Overlay.create('search', map.viz, {})
v.show();
$('#map').append(v.render().el);`

Comment: another solution http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88287/24426